# Pressing browser back button after viewing an updated record redirects me back to edit form Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I know this is an odd question but I have tried searching for this on the Internet everywhere but I just can't find an answer...

So I have created a standard CRUD on a nested resource

```
Route::resource('clients', 'ManageClientsController');
Route::resource('clients.users', 'ManageClientUsersController');
```

All the CRUD activities is working as expected however there is some kind of glitch that I have found and I can't seem to solve it.

Every time I saved an edit form (or update a record) in the ManageClientUsersController I then press the link that goes to the show() method from the index() method just to check if everything is updated and the result is as expected... however... when I press the back button on the browser (I am using Chrome) the back button takes me to the edit form page... where the expected is supposed to the index() method... weird.

Not sure what is going on here. My guess is something todo with sessions?

Many thanks

Comment: Back button is controlled by your browser. I suspect that it just goes to any previous URL that you were at. Sessions should not interfere with back functionality in any way. What is the URL of the "index" page after edit?

Comment: Show your code in `edit` method ?

Comment: @edvinas.me Hi thanks for the reply the URL is admin/clients with return Redirect::route('admin.clients.index'); Just for your info I prefix it with an 'admin' in front Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admin'), function(){